# Filter list of strings starting with specific keyword

Tags: python

How can I find a string (`PartialWord`) inside a List (`WordList`) in Python 2.7?

```
PartialWord = "ab"
WordList = ['absail', 'rehab', 'dolphin']
```

A search with a wildcard like: ab*

Where it would ONLY find the word, if it starts with those letters (i.e. the result should only give absail, but not rehab, despite both having 'ab').

The WordList would be a dictionary, which is over 700KB.

Comment: do you need to find first entry or all of them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may use [`str.startswith(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) along with a *list comprehension* to get the list of the words starting with some string as:

```
>>> PartialWord = "ab"
>>> WordList = ['absail', 'rehab', 'dolphin']

>>> [word for word in WordList if word.startswith(PartialWord)]
['absail']
```

---

As per the [`str.startswith` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

> **str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]]):**
>
> Return `True` if string starts
>   with the *prefix*, otherwise return `False`. *prefix* can also be a `tuple` of
>   prefixes to look for. With optional *start*, test string beginning at
>   that position. With optional *end*, stop comparing string at that
>   position.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

Can you explain why you need  "word for word "?

Comment: @MichaelTenson Take a look at [Python's List Comprehension Document](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/196/list-comprehensions#t=201706041906440415065). It will clarify your doubts.

Comment: I had the same question as @MichaelTenson.  The first 'word' is what's returned by the function in the [], so you could have `word+" "+word` and the code would return ['absail absail']. Note the for loop element `word` is printed (due to the `[word ` part of the command) everytime the if statement evaluates true.  Here's a potentially useful resource: https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/

Answer (score 1):

```
for word in WordList:
    if word.startswith(PartialWord):
        print word
```

Answer (score 0):

As everybody mentioned before, `str.startswith` is your function. You can study regex patterns for more complex operations. [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
>>> WL = ['absail', 'rehab', 'dolphin']
>>> PW="ab"
>>> L=[a for a in WL if a[:len(PW)]==PW]
>>> L
['absail']
```