# (Python) How do I compare a few letters to a whole list of words to find, what words contain the searched-for letters in order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Question says it all basically.

I'm trying to find words that contain specific letters in order.
So if I search for "ers" it should only give out words like "ERStaunding", etc.

That's what I have so far: (doesn't work because a string requires a string as left operand) but you get the idea:

```
sorted = []

for i in range(0,len(words)): #"words" is a list of 1600 words
    if possible in words[i]: #error because of what I said before
        sorted.append(words[i]) #"possible" is a string of letters 

print(sorted)
```

thanks in advance!

edit:

This is what I put in/what comes out: (in pseudocode, it's hangman for uni)

user input: "hello" - word to be guessed

cpu guesses: "h" (for example)
"is h part of your word? (y/n)"

user input: "y"

computer knows that "h" is at position 1 (by comparing to the word that has to be guessed) - stupid, I know but this is an example :D
: h _ _ _ _

now the pc should compare what he has (h up to this point at index 0) to words in a database (in my case words.txt) and only leave the ones that have "h" as their first letter. This process should be interchangeable. For example: if the pc has _ _ l l _, he should still be able to filter the words.

I hope that's what you meant with an example, hope this helps :D

Comment: 1) `sorted()` is a built-in Python function, so don't name your results list that. 2) You can iterate over lists directly (`for word in words:`), so you don't need `range()` and `len()` at all. 3) `possible` should probably contain the string you're looking for. 4) You need to either use `upper()` or `lower()` at some point(s) so you can search in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes, that works, but I'm trying to *teach* the OP how to use various features of the language. I doubt they've covered list comps in class yet.

Comment: @MattDMo ok - lets teach: Dear OP, [edit] your question to contain a [mre] that makes clear what all those variabels are that your code uses. Currently I only get NameError - do you need help with that?

Comment: Duplicate: [filtering-a-list-of-strings-based-on-contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152898/filtering-a-list-of-strings-based-on-contents)   or maybe [filter-list-of-strings-starting-with-specific-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357731/filter-list-of-strings-starting-with-specific-keyword)

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for the help :) I don't use upper or lower 'cause I've imported the whole libary as lowercase. (text = file.read().lower())

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you! I have no Idea how I didn't find those. I've been googling for like 2 hours

Comment: google: `python site:stackoverflow.com filter list with strings for words that contain` gave me plenty of hits :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you just want to check whether the given word is present at the begining.

```
substring=substring.lower()
for i in range(0,len(words)): #"words" is a list of 1600 words
    s=words[i].lower()
    if substring in s: # word found at the begining
        sorted.append(words[i])
```

Comment: Why would they just be searching at the beginning of each word?

Comment: As he said that,  "ers" it should only give out words like "ERStaunding".

I thought he just wanted to check whether the string is present at the begining or not.
i have also updated the code now

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I'm searching the whole word though, not just the beginning. :/

Comment: That works! And a new problem emerged that I hadn't thought of. If I have a list like list = ["t","h"," ","n"," "] if I convert it to a string, it becomes "thn" and I can't filter for words containing exactly "thn" because there are basically none. And It's not the word the PC should be looking for. I'll still mark you as the working answer. Can you help me with this problem too? pretty please? I'm so lost :D

Comment: I imagine i need to convert to a string but fill the remaining spaces with some character, so the PC skips those in its search (like possible = ''.join(substring))

Comment: Can you just give a specific example. As far as i know, you have a list of strings & you want to select those strings which contain a specific value.